# For Loop. Why is it less than < not less than or equal to <=?

Tags: for-loop

Below is a question from a tutorial I'm doing.

Code the first line of a for loop with the usual counter, the usual starting value, and the usual incrementing. Limit the number of loops by the number of elements in the array pets.

My answer is:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= pets.length; i++) {
```

The tutorial answer is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
```

Why is it < if we are trying to find the length of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In programming languages, most of the time, indexes and arrays start at 0 and not 1. So, the first element would be 0, and not 1.

Therefor, you need to put less than as you need to compensate for the numbering system.

Cheers

Comment: Let me know if you understand, as I would like to help

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have an array of size 1. On the first iteration, i would be zero and fulfill both conditions. On the second, i would only fulfill the <=, but remember you've already looped through every element in the array, so you will likely get an error in your loop for trying to access an element not in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are indexed starting with 0, and up to arr.length - 1. The last index does not have the same index value as the length of the array. Notice, that by starting at zero and iterating up to the length of the array minus one, the entire length of the array has still been traversed.

Answer (score 0):

You start counting from 0 and not 1. Consider what would happen if you put in an equals there. It would try to access array[pets.length] which is an array out of bounds exception in most languages. pets.length gives you the NUMBER OF ITEMS in the array. What you need is an index. Starting from 0 and not 1 you can go upto pets.length - 1. Hope that clears it up.